# Flatten an XML with xslt then Import into Access

Tags: xml, vba, csv, ms-access, xslt

I've been trying for 3 weeks to use an XML file in Access. I've tried a couple of tactics such as converting to CSV and having a linked table but favour flattening the XML then importing it with VBA.
I've seen lots of helpful examples and have learned a lot, but none of them let me complete the job. I'm a bit of a novice.
It's important I understand as I need to take on a bigger XML file next, so I'll be adapting the XSLT to suit the bigger file next, inspired by your help.

A snippet of the XML is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<STOREITEMS><PRODUCT ITEM="R7876" NAME="Gloves Pair">
        <STOCK>No Stock.</STOCK></PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT ITEM="BR122293" NAME="Silver Duo Balls">
        <STOCK>In Stock</STOCK></PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT ITEM="cloneboyb" NAME="Cast Your Own Kit">
        <STOCK>In Stock</STOCK></PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT ITEM="ASTRO" NAME="Astroglide">
        <STOCK>In Stock</STOCK></PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT ITEM="3002028110" NAME="Translucence Pink">
    <STOCK>In Stock</STOCK></PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT ITEM="0340" NAME="Cream 82g Lubricant">
        <STOCK>No Stock.</STOCK></PRODUCT>
</STOREITEMS>
```

To be compatible with Access I need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<STOCK>
    <PRODUCT>
        <ITEM>R7876</ITEM>
        <NAME>Gloves Pair</NAME>
        <STOCK>No Stock.</STOCK>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <ITEM>BR122293</ITEM>
        <NAME>Silver Duo Balls</NAME>
        <STOCK>In Stock</STOCK>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <ITEM>cloneboyb</ITEM>
        <NAME>Cast Your Own Kit</NAME>
        <STOCK>In Stock</STOCK>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <ITEM>ASTRO</ITEM>
        <NAME>Astroglide</NAME>
        <STOCK>In Stock</STOCK>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <ITEM>3002028110</ITEM>
        <NAME>Translucence Pink</NAME>
        <STOCK>In Stock</STOCK>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <ITEM>0340</ITEM>
        <NAME>Cream 82g Lubricant</NAME>
        <STOCK>No Stock.</STOCK>
    </PRODUCT>
</STOCK>
```

Most of what I've tried is an adaption of things I've seen elsewhere on here so I don't particularly have a starting point.

The VBA script I'm using to apply the transform and import the new XML file is the following:

```vb
Dim domIn As DOMDocument30
    Dim domOut As DOMDocument30
    Dim domStylesheet As DOMDocument30
    Dim xFile As String
    Dim StyleSheet As String
    Dim NewStock As String

    StyleSheet = "path to XSL"
    xFile = "path to xml"
    NewStock = "path to intended csv"
    Set domIn = New DOMDocument30

    domIn.async = False

    'Open the ADO xml document
    If domIn.Load(xFile) Then

        'Load the stylesheet
        Set domStylesheet = New DOMDocument30
        domStylesheet.Load StyleSheet

    'Apply the transform
    If Not domStylesheet Is Nothing Then
        Set domOut = New DOMDocument30
        domIn.transformNodeToObject domStylesheet, domOut

        'Save the output
        domOut.Save NewStock

        'Import the saved document into Access
        'Application.ImportXML NewStock
    End If
End If

'Cleanup
Set domIn = Nothing
Set domOut = Nothing
Set domStylesheet = Nothing

MsgBox "done!", , "ImportXMLFromADO"
```

I look forward to seeing pointers and thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you need MS Access? XSLT can directly convert XML to CSV. Search this site for such examples.

Comment: Not this xml file. I did try the easiest option first and spent a lot of time on this site looking at examples. Access cannot import attributes, so with the xml file in question, all you get from a straight import is the stock field, with no way of knowing which item it's associated.

Comment: MS access is what we use for our crm and inventory management. It synchronizes to our suppliers, marketplaces and websites. It also connects to our carriers in the warehouse.

Comment: Understood. So you need to save the XML data in database not just convert to CSV.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, consider XSLT to convert XML to CSV. Then, if needed data should be saved as a table, have MS Access import resulting CSV file with [DoCmd.TransferText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.transfertext).

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:variable name="quote">&quot;</xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/STOREITEMS">
      <xsl:text>"ITEM","NAME","STOCK"</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="PRODUCT"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PRODUCT">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, @ITEM, $quote, ',',
                                 $quote, @NAME, $quote, ',', 
                                 $quote, STOCK, $quote)"/>
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()"><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text></xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[XSLT Demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2Do)

**VBA** *(no domOut, only text written to file)*

```vb
Dim domIn As New DOMDocument30, domStylesheet As New DOMDocument30
Dim xFile As String, StyleSheet As String, NewStock As String, xmlText As String
Dim fso As Object, oFile As Object

StyleSheet = "path to XSL"
xFile = "path to xml"
NewStock = "path to intended csv"

'LOAD INPUT XML
domIn.async = False
If domIn.Load(xFile) Then
    'LOAD STYLESHEET
    domStylesheet.Load StyleSheet

    'APPLY TRANSFORMATION, SAVE TO TEXT
    If Not domStylesheet Is Nothing Then
       xmlText = domIn.transformNode(domStylesheet)

       ' SAVE CSV
       Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
       Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(NewStock)
           oFile.WriteLine xmlText
       oFile.Close

       'IMPORT CSV INTO MS ACCESS
       DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , "myTableName", NewStock, True, , 65001
    End If
End If

'CLEAN UP
Set domIn = Nothing: Set domStylesheet = Nothing
Set oFile = Nothing: Set fso = Nothing
```

Comment: Love it, I did have a go at this method but couldn't pull it off. This has worked perfect. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

The XSLT needed seems to be rather basic, just write a template to transform the attributes of `PRODUCT` elements into child elements and handle the rest with the identity transformation template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PRODUCT/@*">
      <xsl:element name="{name()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTAm/1

Comment: Thanks very much, this worked perfect too and I've learned from it. I'll be using this tactic too on some of the other files I need to import.